# Secure Private Key (RSA) with user password (AES)

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I need to heavily encrypt some data in my ASP.NET Core application.

The idea was:
A user will have a hashed password. The user will also have an asymmetric key (RSA-512). The public key is stored in the DB. The private key first gets encrypted by a symmetric key (AES-256). As key for this encryption we use the plain/text password of the user.

If I want to create something as example a car entity. I'll generate a public and private key for this particular car entity. The public keys gets stored in plain text. The private key gets encrypted with the public key of the creator of the 'car' (user).

The fields that belong to the car are than encrypted with the public key of the car.

To decrypt the car. We need the private key of the user because this is needed to decrypt the private key of the car. With this decrypted private key of the car we could decrypt the content of the car.

But to become the private key of the user, I need to decrypt it with the plain/text password. This password is only available once @ login time (it's nowhere stored ofcourse).

The problem I have now is that I'm using a federated login system with IdentityServer 4. This is a different 'project' than my API project(s).

But I need the password in the API because this executes my 'Business Logic'.

**REAL PROBLEM STARTS HERE:**

To solve this problem:

I was thinking of adding a 'route' in my API that my login project can call.
So everytime a user logs in the login project will execute a REST call to the correct API with as message: *'Here is the decrypted version of the private key of user X'.*

At this moment the API will store it in a 'InMemory' EF Core database. Everytime the user needs to decrypt his car data. I need to retrieve the private key from the 'InMemory' DB.

Problem I have here. Is the EF 'InMemory' DB used for this purpose? It looks like it's only used as demo or as testing purpose.

When do I delete private keys for the memory. If a users logsout I can manage it. But when a user 'expires' I'm not able to trigger on this. So his decrypted private key will keep living in memory.

How reliable is the 'InMemory' DB? When does it 'cleans' itself?

I'm gladly to receive some helpful tips.

Sincerely, Brecht

Comment: InMemoryDB is for unit testing mainly, where you can use it to populate and return data instead of relying on a real database

Comment: Also: I am no security expert, but your system/logic seems pretty flawed and beats the basics of security. The private key should never leave the users possession, but what you actually want to do is encrypt it with symetric encryption and then decrypt it on the server? It means both the "client" and the "server" must know it. That beats the whole purpose of it and you could as well just send the private key unencrypted via SSL and would have the same level of security, also the hashed password which should be as secret now just got replaced/used as a password in "plaintext".

Comment: An attacker wouldn't need the real password anymore, he'd just need to get the hashes of your Identity servers DB to access and decrypt all the data. Where is the security here? You won **nothing**. This can only work when the users password is used directly and only then when he enters it to decrypt some data on the client and sent that back to server over a secured channel (SSL with validation etc)

Comment: @Tseng The encryption of the private key (AES) also happens on the server side. This is done so when there is a DB breach nobody can retrieve a valid private key. So the actual private key never gets to the user (clientside). The hackers needs the password in this scenario because otherwise he would never be able to decrypt the private key. 

Thx for your collaboration, If you still spot something insecure please let me know!

Comment: No, they don't need the password because you don't use the password. You only use the **password's hash**, which in this case basically acts as a paintext password. And the **hash** is stored on your Identity server database where they can easily obtain it, if they breach. That's why I said it doesn't add much protection, because all data required to decrypt it is on **your servers**!!! Protection can only be effective if the private key/passphrase is **only in possession of the user** which have to **submit** it when he wants the data decrypted

Comment: This is called _security by obscurity_ and offers barely or no protection at all. If password **and** private key are in possession of the user, then when someone breaches into the servers they have no chance to decrypt the data, **until** the users tries to login / decrypt it for the first time after the breach. If he doesn't his data is safe. In your case, **ALL** users data are automatically compromised in case of a breach, attacker has access to all required data

Comment: I don't only use the hash. The password of the user is used to encrypt the private key, not the hash. So not every data to decrypt is on the DB. You need the the password of the user to decrypt the private key. Because it's encrypted with the password and it's not stored in the DB.

Or am I completely seeing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security issues aside (see comments), the InMemoryDatabase is mainly there for testing or db-less tutorials. Everything you add to it, remains there until [deleted](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory/Storage/Internal/InMemoryTable.cs#L50-L62) (and some times later garbage collected, which you don't really have control over!) or the DbContext is disposed.

Instead of an InMemory EF Core Database, it makes more sense to use memory cache (distributed or local).

You can of course use an distributed cache like Redis and safe the decoded private key in it, and call it from your service. You can add an [expiry](https://redis.io/commands/expire) date, when the key becomes invalidated and needs to be requested or extend the expire time by calling [expire command](https://redis.io/commands/expire) on the key and when user logs out, delete the key with [del](https://redis.io/commands/del).

It works also well, if you scale up your servers. If you start with `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` you can easily switch to Redis later on, as they both implement `IDistributableCache` interface, just change configuration in startup class.

You also may want try using SecureString (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1387#issuecomment-234319572)), which isn't directly implemented in .NET Core but available as extra package [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Security.SecureString)) to keep it for as short as possible in local memory and not to rely that the GC does it at some point.